# Barcode128 appears outside of the pdf page in IE

Tags: java, image, itext, barcode

I am creating an image with Barcode128 and am trying to place it in PDf file, but it is going over the page in IE:
[image: IE_AdobeReader]

if the order number (ETIMS...) is around 20 characters it print normal size barcode.
[image: labe2]

I tried different values for:

```
code128.setBarHeight(); 
code128.setX(); 
Image.setWidthPercentage(); 
Image.scaleAbsolute();
Image.scaleToFit();
Image.scalePercent();
```

But nothing works, it's like something else sets width and height and nothing I do changes it.

parts of the code where this is happening:

```
float[] widths1 = { 10f, 4f };
PdfPTable tableReqNumberBarcode;
Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph();
PdfPCell cellReqNumberBarcode;

while (iteratorPDFReader.hasNext()) 
{
   tableReqNumberBarcode = new PdfPTable(widths1);
   cellReqNumberBarcode = new PdfPCell(p1);
   cellReqNumberBarcode.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER); 
}

page = writer.getImportedPage(pdfReader, pageOfCurrentReaderPDF);
cb.addTemplate(page, 1.15f, 0, 0, 1.15f, 70, 0);
Barcode128 code128 = new Barcode128();                      
code128.setCode(orderNumber);
code128.setFont(null);  //remove printed text under the barcode
code128.setBarHeight(80f); 
code128.setX(1f);

Image myImage = code128.createImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null);
cellReqNumberBarcode.addElement(myImage);

tableReqNumberBarcode.addCell(cellReqNumberBarcode);
document.add(tableReqNumberBarcode);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `code128.setX(1f);` sets the width of the narrowest bar. Set it to a lower value to shrink the barcode.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding setX and setBarHeight()

```
Barcode128 code128 = new Barcode128();                               
code128.setCode(GetReqNumByJobNumber(childJobNumbers[labelNumber], eb, ssb));
code128.setFont(null);  //null removes the printed text under the barcode
code128.setX(0.6f);
code128.setBarHeight(22);
Image myImage = code128.createImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null);
myImage.setAbsolutePosition(10,700);
myImage.scalePercent(125);
```